# consulta de ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Una consulta como hago para agregar mi modelo en una grafica de ggplot2?
tengo mi modelo:

```
model1 <- lm(X ~ poly(DAX,2), data = EuStockMarkets)
```

mis predicciones:

```
predicciones1= predict(object=model1,newdata=nuevas.edades1)
```

y quisiera poner este modelo en mi qplot de ggplot2

```
ggplot(EuStockMarkets, aes(x=X, y=DAX)) +   geom_point() + theme_light()
```

Es una ecuación cuadrática, pero no se como implementar para poner los datos de las predicciones en el nuevo `ggplot` y poner la curva del modelo. Me podrían ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que añadir una capa más de puntos con las predicciones:

```r
ggplot(EuStockMarkets, aes(x=X, y=DAX)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(x=X, y=predicciones1) +
  theme_light()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar una curva de regresión lo natural es usar el [`geom_smooth()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.5/topics/geom_smooth) e indicarle la formula del modelo:

```
ggplot(EuStockMarkets, aes(x=DAX, y=X)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) +
  theme_light()
```

El contexto de `y ~ poly(x, 2)` es el de `ggplot()` por lo que las variables ya no sonlas de `data.frame` sino las definidas en la estética `aes(x=X, y=DAX)`